# Convert Markdown to HTML

Tags: pandoc

I have HTML file which has a text area and writes in markdown format. I would like to convert that markdown text to HTML file? Someone told me pandoc does this option> I tried the demo by applying the text and clicking convert. It works perfectly. Now I am looking for a way to do the same in the background using pandoc on my server.

Is this possible? if so how? I searched the site but couldn't get clear information on this? I am totally new to the web development part.

Thanks!

Comment: Any markdown parser should do. There's likely many options. If you're using JavaScript, you could look into the showdown library, which should take care of what you need. Or you can just Google for markdown parser and find something else that suits your needs or language preference

Comment: @obermillerk will showdown library help save file to html?

Comment: You can take the results of any parser and write them to a file using language APIs for whichever language you use, you don't need the library to do that for you. I bet it's unlikely to find a library that will have that as part of it because it can be handled fairly easily on your end. But I could be wrong, there might be something out there.

Comment: You'll have to pick a server-side technology and ask specifically about that. You'll also have to figure out what you want to do with the HTML file on your server after that. Maybe it makes more sense to do it on the client in JavaScript, or whatever...